# How to read large file at once with Python read()

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Problem

I have a 270,000-line txt file(15M), trying to import with python, but it always shows part or it(about 100,000 lines)

```
with open('a.log', 'r') as f:

    raw_text_data = f.read()
    print(raw_text_data)
```

If use the max_size parameter, it can display the front part.

```
raw_text_data = f.read(1000)
```

Also tried read it in binary mode('rb'), but not working for me.

### question

I don't want to read the txt file in pieces, is there any way to read it into the memory at once?

Comment: Just because you don't see everything printed, doesn't mean you didn't read the file in its entirety. Confirm that `print(len(raw_text_data))` is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Why would you want to read it all at once? Can't you go over line-by-line?

Comment: I have tried <for line in f.readlines():>, but still only part of it.

Comment: Also note that [read()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) is a best-effort [readall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readall). Snippet from `read()` documentation: "Fewer than size bytes may be returned if the operating system call returns fewer than size bytes."
On the other hand `readall()` makes as many system calls as required to read everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that what you are seeing is a result of [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print) output buffering. As a hack you can try using `print(raw_text_data, flush=True)` to bypass output buffering.

**Note** that using `print()` for displaying large amounts of data on STDOUT is **not advised** for the very reason of encountering **buffer overflows**. When displaying large chunks of data, lower level API should be preferred, like [os.write()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.write).

Comment: tried print(raw_text_data, flush=True), but not working.

Comment: See the comments under the question. It may very well be that the bottleneck is the OS limiting the size of the data returned. Try `readall()` instead of `read()`.

Comment: You are right, it is just cosmetic issue.     
```
for line in f.readlines():
        if "PID:" in line:
            print(line)
it shows correctly.